# How to make iOS app name localizable?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to find the easiest way to localize my app. I'm using sqlite, so I need basically only to switch my database name. Problem is the app name - can it be localized from code or I have to make x apps for x languages, so anyone will have app name in his/hers native language? The latter one seems like already rejected app to me... anyone?

Comment: This seems to be good walkthrough : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html

Comment: yeah, I meant "localize", sorry for that

Comment: or "localise", depending on the localisation :-)

Comment: 2024: This is better - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77700539/456536

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I assume you mean the Bundle Display Name that appears on the device's home screen:
You should create a localized file called `InfoPlist.strings` similar to the `Localizable.strings` file that you use for the usual text snippets.

In the `InfoPlist.strings` you can localize the different keys from your Info.plist. To localize the app name add:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My localized app name";
```

To localize a file: Simply create a new strings file in Xcode. Then reveal the right Xcode pane and add localizations via the menu shown here:

[image: XCode localizations]

Using this technique you can localize any file you like. Simply add the correct version to your bundle. If you then use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathFor...` you will automatically get the path to the correct localization. We do this for sqlites, strings and sometime even images.

Comment: works like a charm in 2018

Comment: Wow! So easy! Thanks! It still works in 2020

Comment: Those who are looking for a video tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Wid7r7DNMw
Works fine in 2022

Comment: It works on XCode 15, even on project using String Catalog.