# Change App Name If iPad Change Language Setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am making a bilingual app thai is English and Korean language.
Now, I want my app to change its name whenever the user change the language setting of the device. It the language is set to English the app name is english, and if it in Korean the app name will change to korean.

i know it is possible, because i've seen some apps like that.
How will i able to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think, You can't change the application name.

Comment: but i've seen some apps that does that. It automatically changes the language of the app according to the language setting of the device.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616650/how-to-make-ios-app-name-localizable

Comment: You can change the application contents, not application name. I saying from my knowledge only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to infoPlist.Strings File

Write

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Your App Name In Particular Language";
```

Add the Localization of the file in property

Comment: how will i add the localization?

Comment: Its at the right side of the file. Utilities of the file. There you can see the localization. You can add multiple languages there.

Comment: i received this error"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


"

Comment: Write your app name in that particular language which you are adding.

Comment: i resolved the error. but nothing is happening in the app name. What i did is i set up two CFBundleDisplayName in korean and in english, Is that what it's supposed to be?