# Releasing different mobile versions to different locales

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are about to change the name of our app.
and want to gradually release the change.
Market by market.
The problem is that The app 'display' name on device home screen and Logo is located in the app bundle. so its not something we can change on run time.

for example, I want that the name in UK and USA will be different on the gradual change.

Any idea what can we do ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use app localisation for this. Here you can define local language strings to be used in the app but also localised images.

You can also define a localised app name. This is not fool proof as it will be based on the language code of the users device. But the majority of devices in the UK will be using en_GB and the majority of device in the USA will be using en_US.

This question may help you:

[How to make iOS app name localizable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616650/how-to-make-ios-app-name-localizable)