# How to localize app name in Xcode 15 using String Catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode15

All the resource that I can find is via `CFBundleDisplayName` in the plist. Is there any updated way to do this?

Comment: Actually, there is a new way. I will update that in the answer. I just found out.

Comment: It might be better to remove this question and post your answer on [How to localize bundle display name in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app).

Comment: This has been added to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77704977/541137

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to localize bundle display name in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 4):

1. To localize the app name, we need to do something else. Now create a new **String Catalog** file called `InfoPlist`
2. Add Localized String Values for `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName`
3. Build and verify the changes.

[image]

See more detailed steps at https://imgracehuang.medium.com/how-to-localize-the-app-name-in-xcode-15-using-string-catalog-95b7734a3a38